# compute new RDD from 2 original RDD

Tags: apache-spark

I have 2 RDD in Key-Value type. `RDD1` is `[K,V]`, `RDD2` is `[K,U]`.
The set of K of both `RDD1` and `RDD2` are the same.

I need to *map* to a new `RDD` with `[K, (U-V)/(U+v)]`.
My way is firstly to *join* `RDD1` to

```
val newRDD = RDD1. RDD2.join(RDD2)
```

Then *map* new RDD.

```
newRDD.map(line=> (line._1, (line._2._1-line._2._2)/(line._2._1+line._2._2)))
```

The problem is that set `RDD1( RDD2)` has over 100 million, so the *join* between 2 sets take a very expensive cost as well as a long time(3 mins) to execute.

Are there any better ways to reduce the time of this task?

Comment: What is your current configuration? Do you partition data? How many cores/executors/RAM do you have? I don't say that you will get the results in 5 seconds, but eventually you have to wait for a job to finish :)

Comment: Could you also please update your question by posting your current code? (Stack Overflow provides a "code" tag which you can use to highlight the code block and make it more readable)

Answer (score 0):

Try converting them to `DataFrame` first:

```
val df1 = RDD1.toDF("v_key", "v")
val df2 = RDD2.toDF("u_key", "u")

val newDf = df1.join(df2, $"v_key" === $"u_key")
newDF.select($"v_key", ($"u" - $"v") / ($"u" + $"v")).rdd
```

Aside from being a lot faster (because Spark will do the optimizing for you) I think it reads better.

I should also note that if it were me, I wouldn't do the `.rdd` at the end -- I would leave it a `DataFrame`. But that's me.